# Using telnet in shell script

Tags: shell

I use the telnet command to check if MySQL port is responding.

```
telnet 10.10.10.24 3306
```

I use the ctrl character to disconnect. This is working as expected.
How do I use this command in shell script?

Comment: Actually, do the echo with newlines as Janne propose, and add a sane timeout value with -w.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're just looking to check if the port is open, try:

```
$ nc -zv 10.10.10.24 3306
Connection to localhost 3306 port [tcp/mysql] succeeded!
```

`nc` will return 0 if the port is open and 1 if it is not.  This is quite helpful for scripting as well.  Omit the `v` switch to keep it quiet:

```
if ! nc -z 10.10.10.24 3306
then
    do_something
fi
```

Comment: Thanks. But the -z switch is working on server but not working on another. Do I need to check the version of nc command?

Comment: Perhaps.  What version is the one not working?

Comment: The -z switch is working correctly. I was wrong, ignore the above comment.

Comment: Is there any technique that we can achieve this with only a "telnet" command? I wrote one below but else condition is not working. 

for i in $(cat /tmp/ip_addresses.txt)
do
  conn_test=$(echo "quit" | telnet "$i" 999 2> /dev/null | grep -oP 'Connected(?= to)')
  if [[ "${conn_test}" == "Connected" ]] ; then
     printf '%s\n' "Connection established"
  else
     printf '%s\n' "No Connection"
  fi
done

Answer (score 9):

`nc` is much better for non-interactive usage. Try something like

```
echo -e "\n\n" | nc 10.10.10.24 3306
```

Comment: If I execute this, I get some garbled output, but the command doesn't exit. Does someone know why?

Comment: Hmmm? It should exit.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have nc, you can use bash special files redirectons:

```
head -1 < /dev/tcp/10.10.10.24/3306 >/dev/null && echo MySQL is on || echo MySQL is off
```

Answer (score 2):

To automate telnet script, you should use expect.  See the expect [home page](http://expect.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

This is my script for any specific cases .

```
host=localhost
DATE=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
TIME=`date +%H%M%S`
LOG_OK=/tmp/telnet_ok
LOG_FAIL=/tmp/telnet_falha

for port in 80 25 22 443 110
do
if telnet -c $host $port </dev/null 2>&1 | grep -q Escape; then
  echo "$DATE $TIME  $port: Connected" >> $LOG_OK
else
  echo "$DATE $TIME $port : no connection" >> $LOG_FAIL
fi
done
```

http://fajlinux.com.br/2014/10/10/script-monitorando-via-telnet/

Answer (score 0):

I would use netcat and it's '-w' instead;

```
host:~ user$  nc -w 1 1.2.6.1 3306
?
5.1.57-1~dotdeb.1?WO`rA*L#h?b4z.pmT;i~^;host:~ user$
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to use telnet in bash shell/expect

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
# just do a chmod 755 one the script
# ./YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME.sh $YOUHOST $PORT
# if you get "Escape character is '^]'" as the output it means got connected otherwise it has failed

set ip [lindex $argv 0]
set port [lindex $argv 1]

set timeout 5
spawn telnet $ip $port
expect "'^]'."
```